# How to ignore a key from json while mapping in case class

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

If i have a JSON

`{"name":"jack","email":"jackt@gmail.com"}`

now while mapping this JSON i want only name to be mapped in my case class, for example

`case class Person(name:String)`

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Like you would if the json didn't contain the "email" field: it will be automatically ignored

Comment: can you specify the type of your route is it get or post? you need to use option for the field which is optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import spray.json._


case class Person(name: String)
object PersonFormat extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat1(Person)
}
import PersonFormat._

val source = """{ "name":"jack", "email":"jackt@gmail.com" }"""
source.parseJson.convertTo[Person]
```

You need to define the JsonProtocol with a implicit val.

Comment: Fair enough and how about if you have multi-level of json, can we map it in single case class.

Comment: @Amit, If you feel the answer is correct, mark it correct. Multilevel JSON you need to map it using Map[A, B]

Answer (score -2):

```
    import play.api.libs.json.Json 

    case class Sample(name:String)

    implicit val SampleJosn = Json.reads[Sample]

    val result = Json.parse("""{"name":"jack","email":"jackt@gmail.com"}""").as[Sample]

    val result2 = Json.parse("""{"name":"jack"}""").as[Sample]
```

Your name will be mapped ignoring email.

See here the Fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9nppAtI/0

Comment: actually that's now what author is asking. He is asking if the field is not defined then it should not map if it is mapped then you need to map it.

Comment: this is `play-json` not `spray-json`- or is it done the same

Comment: but in the case class as i can see there is no field where the email is going to be mapped?

Comment: if email is not available then it would not map. Only it will map the name

Comment: @pme its the same slight format change as per spray library

Comment: @Rahul but what if the email is defined and need to use it the further operations. that's why my point is. it's better to use option.

Comment: I understand its good to use Option for further operations but I replied as per the owner of the question demanded.

Comment: @Raman the Solution of @Raman is correct for `play-json`- see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9nppAtI/0